# sqoop into more parts with small sizes

Tags: hadoop, sqoop2, bigdata

I have sqoop stmt with 10 mappers. Entire data is going into 10 parts in hadoop with each part exceeding 1GB. I want to divide the data into multiple files of smaller parts, needless to say more than 10, something like 50 files of 200MB each. However due to DB bottleneck issue, I cant create more than 10 mappers in a sqoop. Let me know if there's any easy solution.

Comment: When you say "However due to DB bottleneck issue, I cant create more than 10 mappers in a sqoop, that means your job will fail if you set more than 10 mappers?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this in direct mode.

You can use `--direct-split-size` (*in Bytes*)

Example:   `--direct-split-size 200000000` will generates files of approx. 200 MB.

Check [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/docs-backup/sqoop/_direct_mode_imports.html) for more details.